Optimizar velocidad de carga sitio web
Me encuentro gestionando un desarrollo para optimizar la carga en un portal, el cual al cargar mas de 1000 registros empieza a alentarse, incluso a veces ya ni carga.
Estoy empezando a entrar en este mundo del desarrollo, realmente no se por donde empezar, encontré un script el cual marca el tiempo de carga de la página, quisiera saber si es aquí en donde tengo que hacer la modificación
<script>
//<![CDATA[ 
// Script que calcula el tiempo de carga de la p�gina.
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
function loadTime() {
    var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    var millisecondsLoading = endTime - startTime;
    document.getElementById('tiempoCarga').innerHTML = "Tiempo de carga: <b>"
            + millisecondsLoading + "ms.</b>";
};
function trim(value) {
    return value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

Gracias!

El script solo calcula el tiempo; su funcionamiento no altera el tiempo de carga.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! asi como esta, no hay nada que decirte porque ese codigo no demuestra nada.

para saber el tiempo de carga de tu pagina y todos los recursos relacionados abre las herramientas del desarrollador en el navegador (ctr + j) y revisa en network, ahi te salen datos reales, un script no te va a dar un dato real porque para cuando el script se empieza a ejecutar ya el html se descargo ...

si dices que es un problema de rendimiento despues de 1000 registros, el problema es ese, debes paginar las consultas a la base de datos y paginarlas en el frontend ... una pagina no deberia cargar mas registros de los que el usuario pueda ver en pantalla por ver (50 - 100 registros por mucho).
